# Django | I'd like to delete a product and all of its related data from the database

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a shopping cart with some items in it. If I delete a product from the basket, I also want to remove it from the ordered item. I am now unable to delete the order items and quantity. I am using ajax to remove items from the cart.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user     = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default = 0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total    = models.DecimalField(default = 0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class OrderItem(models.Model):

    Quantity_Choices =(
    ('one', '1'),
    ('Two', '2'),
    ('Three', '3'),
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=22, choices=Quantity_Choices, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() ==1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)   
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj



    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
```

The code for adding an item to the cart is as follows.

```
def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    print(product_id)
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("No product")
            return render("cart_home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)    
            added= False
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
            added =True    
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_obj.products.count()
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("ajax request")
            json_data = {
                "added":added,
                "removed": not added,
                "cartItemCount":cart_obj.products.count()
            }
            return JsonResponse(json_data)
    return redirect("cart_home")

def productdetails(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    cart, cart_created= Cart.objects.get_or_create(request)
    form =sizeForm(instance=product)
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = sizeForm(request.POST, instance =product)
        if form.is_valid():
            quantity=form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
            print(quantity)
            orderitem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product,cart=cart, quantity=quantity)
            

    context= {
        'object' : product,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'home/productdetails.html', context)
```

[orderitem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KKPa.png)

[cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAgHX.png)

Comment: Can you please show your `CartManager` class?

Comment: please see the code. i have added the card manager details

Comment: Where exactly are you creating the `OrderItem` object? And what do you mean by ` am now unable to delete the order items and quantity` exactly?

Comment: Added the view for the orderitem.